# Maximum value of a function using loops

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a function ab+bc+a/c, where a,b and c ranges from 1 to 5.I have to get an output of maximum value of this function and the values of a,b and c which give that maximum value. Is it possible to do it with loops? Please help me to solve this as I am not familiar with loops...

Comment: Are you going to use the program *Mathematica* for this?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on answer by [Louis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9660/louis) using [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

Return maximum value and associated value of variables (a, b, c) as replacement rules:

```
Module[{max = {0, 0, 0, 0}, val},
 Table[
  If[(val = a*b + b*c + a/c) > First[max],
   max = {val, a, b, c}],
  {a, 5}, {b, 5}, {c, 5}];
 Clear[a, b, c];
 {First[max], Thread[{a, b, c} -> Rest[max]]}]

(*  {51, {a -> 5, b -> 5, c -> 5}}  *)
```

Comparing with [Maximize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html)

```
Maximize[{a*b + b*c + a/c,
  1 <= a <= 5, 1 <= b <= 5, 1 <= c <= 5},
 {a, b, c}, Integers]

(*  {51, {a -> 5, b -> 5, c -> 5}}  *)

% === %%

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

See

[Looping Constructs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LoopingConstructs.html)

Looping is a core concept in programming. The Wolfram Language provides powerful primitives for specifying and controlling looping, not only in traditional procedural programming, but also in other, more modern and streamlined programming paradigms.

```
Table[a b + b c + a/c, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}, {c, 1, 5, 1}]
```

> {{{3, 7/2, 13/3, 21/4, 31/5}, {5, 13/2, 25/3, 41/4, 61/5}, {7, 19/2,
>   37/3, 61/4, 91/5}, {9, 25/2, 49/3, 81/4, 121/5}, {11, 31/2, 61/3,
>   101/4, 151/5}}, {{5, 5, 17/3, 13/2, 37/5}, {8, 9, 32/3, 25/2, 72/
>   5}, {11, 13, 47/3, 37/2, 107/5}, {14, 17, 62/3, 49/2, 142/5}, {17,
>   21, 77/3, 61/2, 177/5}}, {{7, 13/2, 7, 31/4, 43/5}, {11, 23/2, 13,
>   59/4, 83/5}, {15, 33/2, 19, 87/4, 123/5}, {19, 43/2, 25, 115/4,
>   163/5}, {23, 53/2, 31, 143/4, 203/5}}, {{9, 8, 25/3, 9, 49/5}, {14,
>       14, 46/3, 17, 94/5}, {19, 20, 67/3, 25, 139/5}, {24, 26, 88/3, 33,
>       184/5}, {29, 32, 109/3, 41, 229/5}}, {{11, 19/2, 29/3, 41/4,     11}, {17, 33/2, 53/3, 77/4, 21}, {23, 47/2, 77/3, 113/4, 31}, {29,
>   61/2, 101/3, 149/4, 41}, {35, 75/2, 125/3, 185/4, 51}}}